# What rights do I have if a closed source non-distributed in-home application was stolen?

Tags: licensing, gpl, lgpl

I was always wondering about this, because I have been recently reading about many leaks and stolen programs on certain news sites:

If a program (running on a server for example, serving http clients), which is closed source and not released to the public, that uses a LGPL or GPL library gets stolen, can the owner of the program effectively* sue the thief?

- effectively - the company won't be turned down by a judge?

Comment: You shouldn't need to sue the thief; you can press charges via the criminal justice system. But I think this will turn out to be off-topic.

Comment: This question appears to be about legal assistance, explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic]

Comment: A program that links to an LGPL library does not fall under the LGPL itself. A program that uses GPL code and is a derivate work of that does fall under the GPL, but this is only relevant if the derivative work is distributed or published by the copyright owner (you), in which case the owner has to license the derivative work under the GPL. A 3rd party (here: thief) has no authority to grant a license to that code. However, the AGPL requires the whole application to be open to any user. If you used AGPL code without respecting that license, this could cause problems if discovered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a lawyer - this is not legal advise.

You have copyright over the application (or parts of it) that you wrote, so you have a legal claim your rights have been infringed regardless of the status of the open source licenses and your obligation to open-source the code you own the copy right to.

The issue over your obligation to open-source your copyrighted work is a separate legal issue. The theft of the copyrighted material owned by you is still illegal even if you have not fulfilled your obligations to the copyright holder of the libraries.

So the next question "effectively".......How much are yo prepared to spend on lawyers.... Do you know who stole it, do you have proof.....

Comment: If this occurs to you, then you certainly need to obtain legal advice for your jurisdiction. You need to able to show that the work was copyright, and that the other person had access and took it without permission. As a previous expert witness in such a case, I can tell you that the facts are not easy to prove, the costs can be high (in the $100k's), the outcome uncertain, and proper compensation problematic.

Comment: ah cool to know :)